# Open files by zenity and process it one by one

Tags: bash, load, zenity

I would like to use this script to open 5 files by zenity, but each file will be process (by "do") separately. Is it possible?

```
FILES=($(zenity --file-selection --multiple --title "Pick a file"))

    for i in "$FILES"
    do
    fastx_quality_stats -i $i -o ${i%.fastq}quality.txt 
    bash /home/fil/Desktop/Pipeline_MISEQ/fastq_quality_boxplot_graph.sh -i ${i%.fastq}quality.txt -o ${i%fastq}quality_distribution.png
    bash fastx_nucleotide_distribution_graph.sh -i ${i%.fastq}quality.txt -o ${i%.fastq}distribuiton_nucleotides.png
    mv *quality.txt *.png fastq_stat/  
    done
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by "will be processed separately"?

Comment: I choose 5 files and each file will be process by scripts after do. So I choose file 1 2 3 4 5 and in first loop will be process 1 in second loop will be process 2 file etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it seems that the default separator between the filenames is `|` (at least on my machine), so you have to use the `--separator` option to be able to use directly the result:

```
FILES=$(zenity --file-selection --multiple --separator=' ' --title "Pick a file")
for f in $FILES ; do
  echo "File: $f"
done
```

Comment: It is really great idea, I missed for it. for now I am not receiving error, but  results only for the first selected sample :(

Comment: Well: it is working for me. Do you really select several files (with Shift and/or Ctrl keys) ?

Comment: Yes I did :-) If I use echo, I receive the names of all files right. But for my pipe is it problem, I receive only result for first file :-(

Comment: So with ``echo``, you see that the loop is working as expected ? So this is not a ``zenity`` problem anymore...

Comment: I receive this from echo File: /home/fil/Desktop/MISEQ/7102-14_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq /home/fil/Desktop/MISEQ/7102-14_S6_L001_R2_001.fastq /home/fil/Desktop/MISEQ/7123-14_S8_L001_R1_001.fastq /home/fil/Desktop/MISEQ/7123-14_S8_L001_R2_001.fastq
But if I select only one file, everything is OK. If I select more files, I receive only one result for the first file. If echo result wil be : File: /home/fil/Desktop/MISEQ/7102-14_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq File:/home/fil/Desktop/MISEQ/7102-14_S6_L001_R2_001.fastq File:/home/fil/Desktop/MISEQ/7123-14_S8_L001_R1_001.fastq etc. It will be better

Comment: Did you remove the quotes around ``$FILE`` as in my example ?

Comment: I did.. I am trying to use it like echo $f | awk -F ' ' '{print $1"\n"$2"\n"$3"\n"$4}' and each row load separately...

Comment: Ideally you should use hex zero as separator, with --separator=$'\0', as zero is the only character that is not allowed in a path (note: '/' is not allowed in a filename, but it is used in paths). Splitting the result into array elements could then be done by prefixing the command in bash with IFS=$'\0'. Allas, zenity (mine is version 3.28.1) silently rejects a zero as separator. You can try that by redirect to a file: "zenity ... --separator=$'\1' > myfile" and open that with a hex viewer. You will see the 0x01 separator. But with ...=$'\0' you see no separator at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way (note the `--separator` parameter):

```
#! /bin/bash

OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS='-'
FILES=($(zenity --file-selection --multiple --separator='-' --title "Pick a file"))
IFS="$OLDIFS"

for file in "${FILES[@]}"
do
    echo $file
done
```

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/579948/can-simple-scripts-use-gui-file-manager-to-select-file

Comment: It does not work. "fastx_quality_stats: failed to open input file '/home/fil/Desktop/MISEQ/7102-14_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq|/home/fil/Desktop/MISEQ/7102-14_S6_L001_R2_001.fastq|/home/fil/Desktop/MISEQ/7123-14_S8_L001_R1_001.fastq': No such file or directory "